# I want to remove query string added dynamically in a custom php blog CMS

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

Here is the page URL:

> https://cmamassociation.in/blog/?action=viewArticle&articleSlug=Javascript-to-hide-URL

For better SEO purposes I want it to look like:

> https://cmamassociation.in/blog/Javascript-to-hide-URL

I tried so many things using .htaccess but I am not much aware.
I tried like below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index/([a-z]+)/([a-z-]+)$ index.php?action=viewArticle&articleSlug=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Your new URL path does not start with `index/`, so why is your RewriteRule trying to rewrite one that does?

Comment: @CBore thanks for taking time. There is an index.php file in blog folder, so when ever I will use: https://cmamassociation.in/blog/
It will be pointing to index.php file.

Answer (score 1):

Have your htaccess rules file in following manner. This assumes that you are hitting link `http://localhost:80/blog/?action=viewArticle&articleSlug=Javascript-to-hide-URL` in browser.

Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
##Rule for external redirect to browser here.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/blog/?\?action=viewArticle&articleSlug=(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ blog/%1? [R=301,L]

##Rule for internal rewrite here.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)/?$ index.php?action=viewArticle&articleSlug=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: @Mahendra Varma, Could you please do let me know if my solution has worked for you?

Comment: Thanks Ravinder for looking in to it, my apology I was unable to check it. Just upload it on my blog folder/site, seems your solution removes the unwanted string from the URL but the page is not appearing, I am getting an error see the below snip:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S6Fm9qBzD26KFbdHf_XNjPAL7PXTZSUz/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can someone help me on this?